# For-Loop inside of lambda in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, lambda, rdd

Using **rdd.map(lambda x: .....)** in pyspark I need to write a lambda-function that is supposed to format a string.

For example I have a string **"abcdefgh"** and in each row of a column after each two symbols I want to insert "-" in order to get **"ab-cd-ef-gh"**.

How could I implement it using the code like this with right pyspark-syntaxis:

```html
df.rdd.map(lambda x: ((for i in range(10): x[i+2:2] + "-"),)).toDF()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some syntax error in your map function. Try this:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext

rdd = sc.parallelize(["abcdefg", "hijklmno"])  
rdd.collect()
# Out: ['abcdefg', 'hijklmno']

rdd.map(lambda x: '-'.join([x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)])).collect()
# Out:['ab-cd-ef-g', 'hi-jk-lm-no']
```

Alternatively:

```
from  itertools import zip_longest
rdd.map(lambda x: '-'.join(map(''.join, zip_longest(*[iter(x)]*2, fillvalue='')))) \
.collect()
# Out: ['ab-cd-ef-g', 'hi-jk-lm-no']
```

Or even shorter:

```
from textwrap import wrap
rdd.map(lambda x: '-'.join(wrap(x, 2))).collect()
# Out: ['ab-cd-ef-g', 'hi-jk-lm-no']
```

(see [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character))