# How to split string with number without spaces in Python, but 2 digits, 3 digits?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string with numbers, I can split to individual numbers like

```
mynum = '123456'.replace(".", "")
[int(i) for i in mynum]
Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I need to split to 2 digits like

```
[12, 34, 56]
```

also 3 digits

```
[123, 456]
```

Comment: Assuming you want pairs of digits, what would the output be from `12345` ?

Comment: I always have even digits if I want to split for 2 digits

Comment: this might be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 2):

One clean approach would use the remainder:

```py
inp = 123456
nums = []
while inp > 0:
     nums.insert(0, inp % 100)
     inp /= 100

print(nums)  # [12, 34, 56]
```

The above can be easily modified e.g. to use groups of three numbers, instead of two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character

Comment: This has some useful solution as well

Comment: @hanzgs That looks like a potential duplicate...you may hammer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

For two-digit splitting:

```
[int(mynum[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(mynum),2)]
```

For three-digit splitting:

```
[int(mynum[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(mynum),3)]
```

So for n-digit splitting:

```
[int(mynum[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(mynum),n)]
```

Comment: You should probably give a quick explanation into why that works ! 

Note also that your bounds in your first range are probably wrong (you are missing the initial 0 if you want to give a step with no kwargs !). 

Finally, I honestly don't get why you don't just split the string int(mynum[i:i+2]), and have to ressort to base 10 calculations. Answer can be improved !

Comment: @ManuelFaysse Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. The answer is now edited.