# How to slice from abcd to abc bcd in Python

Tags: python

There's an string like this:

```
abcdefghijk
```

I want to slice it like this:

```
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
hij
ijk
```

I googled but could not find any site or answers to reach this.

**Update 1**

My question is not similar to [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "abcdefghijk"
str_list = []
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    new_string = s[i] + s[i+1] + s[i+2]
    str_list.append(new_string)

for x in str_list:
    print(x)
```