# Split string every nth character, excluding hidden characters (e.g. "\033[92m")

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to represent the "qlocktwo" clock in python.

This is the code:
The most important part to the question is the last four lines (I've left the rest to negate any confusion).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from datetime import datetime
import num2words
import string

grid = "itlisasampmacquarterdctwentyfivexhalfstenftopasterunineonesixthreefourfivetwoeightelevenseventwelvetenseoclock"

now = datetime.now()
minute = int(now.strftime("%M"))
hour = int(now.strftime("%H"))

def checkTime(hour, minute):
    if hour >= 12:
        hour -= 12
    t = "past"
    if hour == 0:
        a = "oclock"
    if minute > 30:
        a = 60 - minute
        t = "to"
        hour += 1
        return a, t, hour
    elif minute <= 30:
        a = minute
        t = "past"
        return a, t, hour
    


def round(a):
    for i in range(1, 7):
        i = i * 5
        for j in range(i-2, i + 3):
            if a == j:
                return i

time = checkTime(hour, 0)

if time[0] != 0:
    outMin = num2words.num2words(round(time[0])).replace("-", " ")
else:
    outMin = "oclock"

outHour = num2words.num2words(time[2])

output = (f"it is {outMin} {time[1]} {outHour}").split(" ")

newGrid = grid


for i in output:
    newGrid = newGrid.replace(i, f"\033[92m{i}\033[0m")

for i in [newGrid[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(newGrid), 10)]:
    print(i)
```

At the end, I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/19860698) to split based on the number of characters (in my case, 10), but this also ends up counting hidden characters, such as terminal colors, so it splits on them as well.

So this is the output I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wEe.jpg

Whereas, this is the output I want (but with the colors remaining):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib13N.jpg

Is there a way to split solely on visible characters?

Comment: You could do the split with `newGrid[i:i+10]` first, and then the replace magics separately on the segments.