# How adding 0x to output values to be as hexadecimal input value

Tags: python, hex

I have output

```
New_MS= 102311144
```

I need to make this value as input by read each two number and add 0x to be hexadecimal, if the last number is just one number then should added 0 to end. As like in below

```
New_MS= (0x10, 0x23, 0x11, 0x14, 0x40)
```

Any idea how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform to string, then split every second character (see here: [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) ).

Then left justify your parts:

```py
New_MS = 102311144

str_ms = str(New_MS)

n = 2
split_str_ms = [str_ms[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(str_ms), n)]

ms_txt_list = [f"0x{d.ljust(2, '0')}" for d in split_str_ms]
print(f"({','.join(ms_txt_list)})")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, its near from what I need, but output is ['0x10', '0x23', '0x11', '0x14', '0x40'], I need it New_MS= (0x10, 0x23, 0x11, 0x14, 0x40) exactly  same Brackets () and no comma ''

Answer (score 0):

I know we shouldn't provide answers without having OP show his work, but it's almost christmas. Here is my shot:

```
New_MS= 102311144

s = f"{New_MS}"
start = 0
t = ()
while s[start:start+2]:
    chunk = s[start:start+2]
    if len(chunk) == 1:
        chunk += "0"

    t += (int(chunk, 16),)

    start += 2

print(t)
```

Comment: OK it good but the output is (16, 35, 17, 20, 64) not (0x10, 0x23, 0x11, 0x14, 0x40) what I asked for

Comment: Your request shows not a tuple of strings, but a tuple of integers. These values are the same.