# Joining every four strings in a list

Tags: python, list, join

I have a list like this:

```
['Ww','Aa','Bb','Cc','ww','AA','BB','CC']
```

And continuing in such a pattern, with varying capitals and lowercases. 
What I want to do is join every four items in this list together. So, the resulting new list (given the one above) would look like this:

```
['WwAaBbCc', "wwAABBCC']
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: Edited the title. I was going to ask something else and then changed my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = ['Ww','Aa','Bb','Cc','ww','AA','BB','CC']
>>> [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(L)] * 4)]
['WwAaBbCc', 'wwAABBCC']
```

Comment: Nice, but why not use `map(''.join,zip(*[iter(L)] * 4))`?

Comment: @jamylak: LCs are preferred to `map()` for some reason.

Comment: I hate that :D Anyway this is my favorite way although I like `map`

Comment: You can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = ['Ww','Aa','Bb','Cc','ww','AA','BB','CC']
[''.join(my_list[i:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 4)]
```

Comment: Haha just posted my answer to see that you had posted the exact same solution.  +1

Comment: here's the error I get:    new_Final = [''.join(final[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(final), 4)] 
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (the arrow points to the last bracket)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
def _get_chunks(lVals, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lVals), size):
        yield lVals[i: i + size]

data = ['Ww','Aa','Bb','Cc','ww','AA','BB','CC']


output = [''.join(chunk) for chunk in _get_chunks(data, 4)]
>>> ['WwAaBbCc', 'wwAABBCC']
```