# How to call a function with parameters as matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability, probability-density

I am trying to call [`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) with four different parameters for mu and sigma. And then for each generated probability density function I need to call that pdf on an array of say, 10 values.

For simplicity let's say that above mentioned function is `addXY`:

```
def addXY(x, y):
    return x+y

params=[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5]]       # mu and sigma, four versions
inputs=[1,2,3]                         # values, in this case 3 of them

matrix = []
for pdf_params in params:
    row = []
    for inp in inputs:
        entry = addXY(*pdf_params) 
        row.append(entry*inp)
    matrix.append(row)
print matrix
```

1. Is this pythonic?
2. Is there a way to pass params and inputs and get a matrix with all combinations in it that is more pythonic/vectorized/faster?

!Important notice: Inputs in the example are scalar values (I've set scalar values to simplify problem description, I am actually using array of n-dimensional vectors and thus **multivariate**_normal pdf).

Hints and tips about similar operations are welcome.

Comment: *"I've set scalar values to simplify problem description..."*  Heh, I think you simplified too much :) (see my answer).  How about showing a more appropriate example?  You'll need each *mu* to be an n-dimensional vector, and each "sigma" will actually be an n-by-n covariance matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Is it possible to do it with the updated info?

Comment: Unforunately it looks like `multivariate_normal.pdf` does not broadcast its arguments, so you'll have write a loop to handle different mean and covariance values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of what you are trying to compute, you don't need `multivariate_normal`.  You are calling the PDF method with a set of scalar values for a distribution with a scalar mu and sigma.  So you can use the `pdf()` method of [`scipy.stats.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).  This method will [*broadcast*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) its arguments, so by passing in arrays with the proper shape, you can compute the PDF for the different values of mu and sigma in one call.  Here's an example.

Here are your `x` values (you called them `inputs`), and the parameters:

```
In [23]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [24]: params = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]])
```

For convenience, separate the parameters into arrays of mu and sigma values.

```
In [25]: mu = params[:, 0]

In [26]: sig = params[:, 1]
```

We'll use `scipy.stats.norm` to compute the PDF.

```
In [27]: from scipy.stats import norm
```

This call computes the PDF for the desired combinations of `x` and parameters.  `mu.reshape(-1, 1)` and `sig.reshape(-1, 1)` are 2D arrays with shape (4, 1).  `x` has shape (3,), so when these arguments are broadcast, the result has shape (4, 3).  Each row is the PDF evaluated at `x` for one of the pairs of mu and sigma.

```
In [28]: p = norm.pdf(x, loc=mu.reshape(-1, 1), scale=sig.reshape(-1, 1))

In [29]: p
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0.19947114,  0.17603266,  0.12098536],
       [ 0.13298076,  0.12579441,  0.10648267],
       [ 0.09973557,  0.09666703,  0.08801633],
       [ 0.07978846,  0.07820854,  0.07365403]])
```

In other words, the rows of `p` are:

```
norm.pdf(x, loc=mu[0], scale=sig[0])
norm.pdf(x, loc=mu[1], scale=sig[1])
norm.pdf(x, loc=mu[2], scale=sig[2])
norm.pdf(x, loc=mu[3], scale=sig[3])
```

Comment: I have just previewed the answer and I believe that it is the solution to my question, but I have one addition to add and would be really nice if you updated your question. In the given example I used function addXY and scalar values for input for the sake of simplifying the problem description. I would of course use an array of vectors, not scalars,  for multivariate_normal pdf input.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my idea to shorten the code and utilize more library.

In your code, in fact, you do not use numpy, scipy. Question will be whether you would like to use numpy.array for further data processing.

Option 1: just use list to present array and list of list to present matrix:

```
from itertools import product
matrix_list = [sum(param)*input_x for param, input_x in product(params, inputs)]
matrix = zip(*[iter(matrix_list)]*len(inputs))
print matrix
```

Credit for using zip method should be given to 
[convert a flat list to list of list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124751/convert-a-flat-list-to-list-of-list-in-python)

Option 2: use numpy.array and numpy.matrix for further processing

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
matrix_array = np.array([sum(param)*input_x for param, input_x in      product(params, inputs)])
matrix = matrix_array.reshape(len(params),len(inputs))
print matrix
```

Comment: Yes but the addXY function above is a dummy function used for simplifying the example. Actual function is multivariate_normal with with inputs of n-dimensional vectors. Thanks for trying anyways!