# How to make list of lists from a flat list given specific elements in Python

Tags: python, list

There is a way to "unflatten" a list in Python (see, for example, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124751/convert-a-flat-list-to-list-of-lists-in-python)). However, how to do that efficiently given specific elements? Here is a slightly altered beginning of Jane Austen's "Pride and Prejudice":

```
Austen = """ONE: It is a truth universally acknowledged, ONE: that a single man in possession
of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.

TWO: However little known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his
first entering a neighbourhood, ONE: this truth is so well fixed in the minds
of the surrounding families, THREE: that he is considered as the rightful
property of some one or other of their daughters.

TWO: "My dear Mr. Bennet," said his lady to him one day, ONE: "have you heard that
Netherfield Park is let at last?"
"""
```

Note, there are some added points:

```
BREAK_POINTS = ('ONE:', 'TWO:', 'THREE:')
```

Using RegEx Tokenizer from `nltk` it is quite easy to get the list of word tokens:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\s+', gaps=True)

tokens = []
for line in Austen.splitlines():
    if line == '':
        continue
    tokens += tokenizer.tokenize(line)

tokens
['ONE:', 'It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally',
'acknowledged,', 'ONE:', 'that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in',
'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good', 'fortune,', 'must', 'be', 'in',
'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife.', 'TWO:', 'However', 'little', 'known',
'the', 'feelings', 'or', 'views', 'of', 'such', 'a', 'man', 'may',
'be', 'on', 'his', 'first', 'entering', 'a', 'neighbourhood,',
'ONE:', 'this', 'truth', 'is', 'so', 'well', 'fixed', 'in', 'the',
'minds', 'of', 'the', 'surrounding', 'families,', 'THREE:', 'that',
'he', 'is', 'considered', 'as', 'the', 'rightful', 'property', 'of',
'some', 'one', 'or', 'other', 'of', 'their', 'daughters.', 'TWO:',
'"My', 'dear', 'Mr.', 'Bennet,"', 'said', 'his', 'lady', 'to',
'him', 'one', 'day,', 'ONE:', '"have', 'you', 'heard', 'that',
'Netherfield', 'Park', 'is', 'let', 'at', 'last?"']
```

How can I "unflatten" that list using `BREAK_POINT`. In particular, if a BREAK_POINT repeats, like the first two `'ONE'`, that should be ignored.

```
[['ONE:', 'It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged,',
'that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in', 'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good',
'fortune,', 'must', 'be', 'in', 'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife.'],
['TWO:', 'However', 'little', 'known', 'the', 'feelings', 'or',
'views', 'of', 'such', 'a', 'man', 'may', 'be', 'on', 'his',
'first', 'entering', 'a', 'neighbourhood,'], ['ONE:', 'this',
'truth', 'is', 'so', 'well', 'fixed', 'in', 'the', 'minds', 'of',
'the', 'surrounding', 'families,'], ['THREE:', 'that', 'he', 'is',
'considered', 'as', 'the', 'rightful', 'property', 'of', 'some',
'one', 'or', 'other', 'of', 'their', 'daughters.'], ['TWO:', '"My',
'dear', 'Mr.', 'Bennet,"', 'said', 'his', 'lady', 'to', 'him',
'one', 'day,'], ['ONE:', '"have', 'you', 'heard', 'that',
'Netherfield', 'Park', 'is', 'let', 'at', 'last?"']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first build a list with all positions of breakpoints with their index in the list. Then use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to avoid adjacent duplicates and return only the indices of the start of each "new" list.
Build the new list by iteration through that index list with [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
import itertools

points = [(i,x) for i, x in enumerate(token) if x in BREAK_POINTS]

points_cleaned = [list(group)[0][0] for _, group in itertools.groupby(points, key=lambda tup: tup[1])]
print(points_cleaned)
# [0, 25, 45, 59, 76, 88]

result = [token[start:end] for start,end in itertools.zip_longest(points_cleaned, points_cleaned[1:])]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['ONE', 'It', 'is', 'a', 'truth', 'universally', 'acknowledged', 'ONE', 'that', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'in', 'possession', 'of', 'a', 'good', 'fortune', 'must', 'be', 'in', 'want', 'of', 'a', 'wife'], 
    ['TWO', 'However', 'little', 'known', 'the', 'feelings', 'or', 'views', 'of', 'such', 'a', 'man', 'may', 'be', 'on', 'his', 'first', 'entering', 'a', 'neighbourhood'], 
    ['ONE', 'this', 'truth', 'is', 'so', 'well', 'fixed', 'in', 'the', 'minds', 'of', 'the', 'surrounding', 'families'], 
    ['THREE', 'that', 'he', 'is', 'considered', 'as', 'the', 'rightful', 'property', 'of', 'some', 'one', 'or', 'other', 'of', 'their', 'daughters'], 
    ['TWO', 'My', 'dear', 'Mr', 'Bennet', 'said', 'his', 'lady', 'to', 'him', 'one', 'day'], 
    ['ONE', 'have', 'you', 'heard', 'that', 'Netherfield', 'Park', 'is', 'let', 'at', 'last']
]
```