# Methods of List comprehension, join a list with a different string at set intervals. (language agnostic)

Tags: arrays, list, language-agnostic, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm interested in possible ways that different languages can Join an array, but rather than using a single join string, using a different join string at given intervals.

For example (hypothetical language):

```
Array.modJoin([mod, char], ...)
e.g. [1,2,3,4,5].modJoin( [1, ","], [2, ":"] )
```

Where the arguments specify an array or object containing a modulo and a join char, the implementation would check which order of modulo took precedence (the latest one), and apply the join char. (requiring that the [mod,char]'s were provided in ascending mod order)

i.e.

```
if (index % (nth mod) == 0) 
  append (join char) 
  continue to next index 
else 
  (nth mod)-- repeat

when complete join with ""
```

For example, I've come up with the following in Ruby, but I suspect better / more elegant methods exist, and that's what I'd like to see.

```
#Create test Array 
#9472 - 9727 as HTML Entities (unicode box chars)
range       = (9472..9727).to_a.map{|u| "&##{u};" }
```

Assuming we have a list of mod's and join chars, we have to stipulate that mods increase in value as the list progresses.

```
mod_joins   = [{m:1, c:",", m:12, c:"<br/>"]
```

Now process the `range` with `mod_joins`

```
processed = range.each_with_index.map { |e, i| 
  m = nil
  mods.reverse_each {|j|
    m = j and break if i % j[:m] == 0
  }
  # use the lowest mod for index 0
  m = mods[0] if i == 0 
  m = nil ? e : "#{e}#{m[:c]}"
}

#output the result string
puts processed.join ""
```

From this we have a list of htmlEntities, separated by `,` unless it's index is a 12th modulo in which case it's a `<br/>`

So, I'm interested for ways this can be done more elegantly, primarily in functional languages like Haskell, F#, Common Lisp (Scheme, Clojure) etc. but also cool ways to achieve this in general purpose languages that have list comprehension extensions such as C# with Linq, Ruby and Python or even Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a simpler and more readable solution in Ruby

```
array = (9472..9727).map{|u|"&##{u};"}
array.each_slice(12).collect{|each|each.join(",")}.join("<br/>")
```

or for the general case

```
module Enumerable   
  def fancy_join(instructions)
    return self.join if instructions.empty?
    separator = instructions.delete(mod = instructions.keys.max)
    self.each_slice(mod).collect{|each|each.fancy_join(instructions.dup)}.join(separator)
  end
end

range = (9472..9727).map{|u|"&##{u};"}
instructions = {1=>",",12=>"<br/>"}

puts array.fancy_join(instructions)
```

Comment: Very nice work, I had no idea `each_slice` existed. This looks like a probably Green tick, I'll wait until tomorrow to see if there's anything better. I think it's unlikely though. And this automatically takes care of the index 0 problem.

Comment: @slomojo `each_slice` and its sibling `each_cons` are very powerful indeed. I’ve added code to cover the general case.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to come back and ask for the mulitiple arguments case.

Comment: If you were going to add `instruction.empty?` you should thrown an error, rather than doing a regular join.

Comment: Yes and yes. You need to anchor the recursion, either by testing for being at the end of your instructions or by testing for slices of length 1 using `return self if self.size == 1` (though in that case your instructions MUST provide a separator for mod 1, so for example `array.fancy_join(4=>",",12=>";")` would not work while it works with above code).

Comment: Yep, just noticed the recursion, scuse me.

Comment: That's a slight problem with the mod 1, but not difficult to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-functional version written in Python. I'm sure it can be adapted easily enough to other languages.

```
import itertools

def calcsep(num, sepspecs):
  '''
    num: current character position
    sepspecs: dict containing modulus:separator entries
  '''
  mods = reversed(sorted(sepspecs))
  return sepspecs[next(x for x in mods if num % x == 0)]

vector = [str(x) for x in range(12)]

result = [y for ix, el in enumerate(vector)
            for y in (calcsep(ix, {1:'.', 3:',', 5:';'}), el)]

print ''.join(itertools.islice(result, 1, None))
```

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here and say that Ruby seems to be able to do it a bit cleaner, also I didn't really mean port my implementation to another language, while losing brevity, I meant use novel features of the language to improve the readability of the routine.

Comment: It can do it more concisely and tersely. "Cleaner" is usually a matter of taste.

Comment: Of course, it's definitely a matter of taste, for example, my `do something if condition` is a bit of a perlism. I meant cleaner as in not having to reverse the mods explicitly and then process them.

Comment: I suppose without the usage directly underneath, it's looking better (my initial reaction was at a glance.) Excuse me.

Comment: by the way, it's not a separator, it's a concatenator. So the names  `joinspecs` and `concatentator` (or similar are more on point)

Comment: Equally, `num: array index position`

Comment: [Python calls it a separator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), so I maintained that terminology.

Comment: Ah, I see, the array is passed to the string method.

Comment: As for the "porting" bit, I didn't even look at your code before writing this; call it "homogenous convergence".

Comment: If you've got it in you, I'd love to see a more concise / terse implementation.

Comment: I can make it more concise by inlining everything, but writing terse Python is... harder than it looks.

Comment: I don't doubt it ("homogenous convergence") what I'm really interested in is if a language like Haskell has this sort of thing licked, or if it's still really a `.map` job.

Comment: If it's essentially the same implementation, not to worry. (definitely didn't mean to offend with the porting remark, just trying to clarify what I'm seeking.)

Comment: One could be clever and write code that uses stepped slice assignment to replace the appropriate separators, but I would be hard-pressed to call that an improvement over the functional version.

Comment: I see, the main "clean" part is about semantics when it comes to list comprehension, `for` is appearing a lot, where Ruby (lisp, linq, etc.) have a lot special purpose of enumerators. They all boil down to the same thing of course, although each one method can be optimised for their specific case in the compiler/interpreter. This is the interesting bit, for me at least.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't really sound like an improvement. The functional version is the way to go.

Comment: Hope you see @akuhn's answer, it's things like this that make Ruby very nice.

Comment: It's nothing that couldn't be done in Python, except `each_slice()` becomes [zip-iter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2233204/20862).

Comment: Oh, very nice. Is this the stepped slice you referred to?

Comment: Have to say, the Ruby is eminently more readable, and also module imports, just core library.

Comment: No, stepped slice assignment is `foo[n::m] = someseq`. `zip()` will take one from whatever is there; 3 will result in 3 taken, 5 will result in 5, etc.