# Change the numbers of a list to another number python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which has a range of numbers from `0` to `1`:

`[0.01,0.1,0.4,0.034,0.6,0.7,0.9,1]`

How would I be able to edit the list so all the numbers from `0-0.5` to `0.4` and change all the numbers from `0.6-1` to `0.7`, so the list becomes:

`[0.4,0.40.40.4,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7]`

```
confindencenumbers = [(x=0.4) for x in confindencenumbers if x < 0.4]
confindencenumbers = [(x=0.7} for x in confindencenumbers if x > 0.5]
```

Comment: Really, there has to be some restriction you are not telling us, else it would be too trivial.

Comment: I've [already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163394/turning-a-list-into-a-tuple-python#comment23098912_16163394) to research, or try something yourself, before you ask. This is a very simple problem.

Comment: That's [not a valid list comprehension](http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html)

Comment: Thats why I need help

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension

Comment: Downvoted. Lack of research in this as well as past questions of the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> l = [0.01, 0.1, 0.4, 0.034, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1]
>>> [0.4 if (0. < f < 0.5) else 0.7 for f in l]
[0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0.4 if 0 <= x <= 0.5 else 0.7 if 0.6 <= x <= 1 else DEFAULT_VAL for x in L]
```