# Merging some elements inside a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Given this nested list:

```
nested_lst = [u'Tom', ['50', ' 1.85', ' 112', ' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115']]
```

I'd like to join every 3 elements of `nested_lst[1]` for the result of:

```
nested_lst = [u'Tom', [('50', ' 1.85', ' 112'), (' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115')]]
```

Comment: Sorry, book recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow, they simply do not fit the format here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok, clear ... I will remove my answer for clearity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> nested_lst = [u'Tom', ['50', ' 1.85', ' 112', ' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115']]
>>> x=nested_lst[1]

>>> nested_lst[1]=[ tuple(x[i:i+3]) for i in xrange(0,len(x),3) ]
>>> nested_lst
[u'Tom', [('50', ' 1.85', ' 112'), (' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115')]]
```

or you can also use `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> nested_lst = [u'Tom', ['50', ' 1.85', ' 112', ' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115']]
>>> x=nested_lst[1]
>>> it=iter(x)

>>> nested_lst[1]=[tuple( islice(it,3) ) for i in xrange(len(x)/3)]
>>> nested_lst
[u'Tom', [('50', ' 1.85', ' 112'), (' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd use a list comprehension like @AshwiniChaudhary has posted, but here's an alternate solution using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

```
>>> nested_lst = [u'Tom', ['50', ' 1.85', ' 112', ' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115']]
>>> [nested_lst[0], zip(*[iter(nested_lst[1])]*3)]
[u'Tom', [('50', ' 1.85', ' 112'), (' 60', ' 1.90', ' 115')]]
```