# Compacting tuples from a QS

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension

What's the Pythonic way to convert this list of tuples to a simpler list of tuples?

```
import urllib.parse
QS='field=var1&save=stringA&field=var2&save=&field=var3&save=stringC'
urllib.parse.parse_qsl(QS, keep_blank_values=True)
>>> [('field', 'var1'), ('save', 'stringA'), ('field', 'var2'), ('save', ''), ('field', 'var3'), ('save', 'stringC')]
```

*Python magic occurs here*

```
>>> [('var1', 'stringA'), ('var2', ''), ('var3', 'stringC')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = [('field', 'var1'), ('save', 'stringA'), ('field', 'var2'), ('save', ''), ('field', 'var3'), ('save', 'stringC')]
>>> [(field[1], save[1]) for field, save in zip(*[iter(data)]*2)]
[('var1', 'stringA'), ('var2', ''), ('var3', 'stringC')]
```

[How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Another way:

```
>>> items = (x[1] for x in data)
>>> list(zip(*[items]*2))
[('var1', 'stringA'), ('var2', ''), ('var3', 'stringC')]
```