# list to map in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a list and I want to convert this list into map

```
mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
```

mylist is equivalent to

```
mylist = [Key,Value,Key,Value,Key,Value]
```

So Input:

```
mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
```

Output:

```
mymap = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

P.S: I already have written following function that do same work, but I want to use iterator tools of python:

```
def fun():
    mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
    mymap={}
    count = 0
    for value in mylist:
        if not count%2:
            mymap[value] = mylist[count+1]
        count = count+1
    return mymap
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `iter` and dict-comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
>>> it = iter(mylist)
>>> {k: next(it) for k in it}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Using `zip` and `iter`:

```
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(mylist)]*2)) #use `itertools.izip` if the list is huge.
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Related: [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: That second solution is beautiful.

Comment: Ashwini, Can you please explain your second solution ??

Comment: @Anurag [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: `it = iter(mylist); dict(zip(it, it))` if you want the second solution as a two-liner that mirrors the first solution.

Comment: Also a slicing solution: `dict(zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2]))`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]
>>> zippedlist = zip(mylist [0::2],mylist [1::2]) #slicing magic
>>> zippedlist
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> dictedlist = dict(zippedlist)
>>> dictedlist 
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

This works because of slicing `[start:stop:skip]`

list starting at 0, skipping 2

zipped with

list starting at 1, skipping 2

Answer (score 1):

To get all the keys from the list you can do:

```
keys = mylist[::2]
```

where the mylist[::2] creates a new list by iterating over every second element in mylist starting at index 0.

To get all the values from the list you can do:

```
vals = mylist[1::2]
```

where the `mylist[1::2]` creates a new list by iterating over every second element in mylist starting at index 1.

and then you can just use dict and zip:

```
dict(zip(keys,vals))  # or all in one line
dict(zip(mylist[::2], mylist[1::2]))
```

zip takes two lists like `["a","b","c"]` and `[1,2,3]` and "zips" them together to give a list like

```
[("a",1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]
```

and `dict` takes an iterable of pairs and turns them into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Using Compress and Cycle:-

```
from itertools import compress
from itertools import cycle

def fun(mylist):
    keys = compress(mylist,cycle([1,0]))
    values = compress(mylist,cycle([0,1]))
    mymap = dict(zip(keys,values))
    return mymap

mylist = ["a",1,"b",2,"c",3]

fun(mylist)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```