# Convert a string with 2-tier delimiters into a dictionary - python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, types, tuples

Given a string:

```
s = 'x\t1\ny\t2\nz\t3'
```

I want to convert into a dictionary:

```
sdic = {'x':'1','y':'2','z':'3'}
```

I got it to work by doing this:

```
sdic = dict([tuple(j.split("\t")) for j in [i for i in s.split('\n')]])
```

First: `['x\t1','y\t2','z\t3'] # str.split('\n')`

Then: `[('x','1'),('y','2'),('z','3')] # tuples([str.split('\t')])`

Finally: `{'x':'1', 'y':'2', 'z':'3'} # dict([tuples])`

**But is there a simpler way to convert a string with 2-tier delimiters into a dictionary?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a little verbose in your walking through list comprehensions:

```
>>> s = 'x\t1\ny\t2\nz\t3'
>>> dd = dict(ss.split('\t') for ss in s.split('\n'))
>>> dd
{'x': '1', 'y': '2', 'z': '3'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'x\t1\ny\t2\nz\t3'
>>> spl = s.split()
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(spl)]*2))
{'y': '2', 'x': '1', 'z': '3'}
```

`str.split()` takes care of all type of white-space characters. If the delimiters  were `*` and `$` for example, then you could use `re.split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'x*1$y*2$z*3'
>>> spl = re.split(r'[*$]{1}', s)
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(spl)]*2))
{'y': '2', 'x': '1', 'z': '3'}
```

Related: [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> m = [ (i[0], i[2]) for i in s.split("\n") ]
>>> m
[('x', '1'), ('y', '2'), ('z', '3')]
>>> d = dict(m)
>>> d
{'y': '2', 'x': '1', 'z': '3'}
```