# How to reverse string with stride via Python String slicing

Tags: python, string, slice

I need to reverse an interleaved string, means i have 2-pairs which shouldt get messed up like this:

```
>>> interleaved = "123456"
```

reversing

```
>>> print interleaved[::-1]
654321
```

but what i actually want is

```
563412
```

is there a string slice operation for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For even length strings this should do it:

```
>>> s = "123456"
>>> it = reversed(s)
>>> ''.join(next(it) + x for x in it)
'563412'
```

For odd length strings, you need to prepend the first character separately:

```
>>> s = "7123456"
>>> it = reversed(s)
>>> (s[0] if len(s)%2 else '') + ''.join(next(it) + x for x in it)
'7563412'
```

---

Using slicing and `zip`:

```
>>> s = "7123456"
>>> (s[0] if len(s)%2 else '') + ''.join(x+y for x, y in zip(s[-2::-2], s[::-2]))
'7563412'
```

Comment: Really creative, I liked your approach

Comment: Ashwini can you explain `next(it) + x for x in it` for me. I understand `next` and for loop expression but complete expression tricky to me.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `reversed` returns an reversed iterator. Now during iteration the for-loop will call `next` on this iterator, but as we need the next item as well, so we call one more additional `next` inside the loop to get the next item. So, in the first iteration `x` will fetch `'6'` and `next(x)` will return `'5'` and so on...

Comment: I tried `>>> for x in it: next(it) + x` after reading your response in comment now it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure that either the `reversed` iterator knows about unicode strings, or that you are not in fact reversing unicode strings. Those are different beasts with combining characters and so on that needs to be handled differently than just reversing the sequence of all the individual characters.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way as far as I know would be to use a regex:

```
import re
''.join(re.findall('..?', '123456', flags=re.S)[::-1])
```

- Input: '123456'
- Output: '563412'

This also works for odd-length strings without having to implement separate logic for them.

Answer (score 3):

You can bring several ideas to [split a string in pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character) and then reverse each piece and reassemble (join) the list reversed too.

E.g. (using satomacoto answer in a not-so-readable way...)

```
''.join([a[::-1][i:i+2][::-1] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)])
```

or (using F.J. answer)

```
''.join(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(a)]*2))[::-1])
```

and so on. (Being `a` your string).

Comment: What is the need of `[`  `]`  in `[iter(a)]` can you explain `(*[iter(a)]*2)` for me?

Comment: In case some one have some question my doubt clear from here [How does `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` work in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: I was pointing you also to [this SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python) and [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) but in fact the A you've found cover better the topic.

Comment: Actually my doubt could clear from edit part in linked question. any ways I want to thank you that I could know the trick from your answer.

Comment: though the knowledge was already out there in SO, I've just unburied it for the OP's current question :)

Comment: yup, I am Python learner,today I am trying to explore from current question and all answers includes good tricks.