# Understanding a line of code

Tags: python

I have been given, by someone else, a line of code that I am having trouble understanding.

```
inputString = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]"

a = inputString[1:-1].split(',')
z = zip(a[::2],a[1::2]) # this line
print a
print z
```

I understand the `split` function and how that is operating. I even understand the `zip` function. What I don't understand is what `a[::2],a(1::2)` is doing. I have tried modifying these bits of code and get varying results, but nothing that allows me to comprehend what modifying the code does. I am fairly new at Python, and could use a little help.

Typical, unmodified result from the code looks like this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
[('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6'), ('7', '8'), ('9', '10'), ('11', '12')]
```

I am trying to get the result of 'a' to split into groups of 4 instead of groups of two, ie:

```
('1','2','3','4'),('5','6','7','8')....etc.
```

Comment: please see explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation

Comment: You should really look into the [`itertools` recipe `grouper`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z = zip(a[::2],a[1::2])
```

The above line twice uses [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) to step through list `a`.   `a[::2]` is telling Python to get every other item in `a`. Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lst[::2]  # Every other item (every item counting by 2's)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>>
```

`a[1::2]` is telling Python to get every other item in `a` starting at index `1`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> lst[1::2]  # Remember that Python indexes start at 0
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>>
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is then pairing-up the items in the lists returned by `a[::2]` and `a[1::2]`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
>>>
```

---

To get the four-item tuples in your example, you can use the following:

```
>>> inputString = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]"
>>> a = inputString[1:-1].split(',')
>>> zip(*[iter(a)]*4)
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('5', '6', '7', '8'), ('9', '10', '11', '12')]
>>>
```

You might also want to read: [How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. In the list of numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], the number '1' is considered index position '0'?

Comment: @SnapperTrx - Yes.  Python indexes are like C/C++ indexes: they start at index `0`.

Comment: Instead of zip, you can also use list comprehension and enumerate, like so: print [(x,y) for x, y in enumerate(s) if x%2!=0]

Answer (score 0):

If you want 4-tuples then you need to use 4 arguments and a stride of 4.

```
z = zip(a[::4], a[1::4], a[2::4], a[3::4])
```