# How to do something to an iterator, then something else to the next iterator in python

Tags: python

What's the 'correct' python way of doing something to the first element, but something else to the second, and something different again for the third in a list, then repeat, eg:

```
a = [2, "foo1", "bar1", 5, "foo3", "bar2", 3, "foo2", "bar3"]
my_function(a)
```

should give

```
20
foo1
foobar1
50
foo3
foobar2
30
foo2
foobar3
```

where "my_function" would be something like:

```
def my_function(a):
    i = 0
    for line in a:
        if i == 0:
            line = line*10
        if i == 2:
            line = "foo"+line
        i = i + 1
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
        print line
```

But this looks very 'unpython'. Is there a better way of doing this, without an `int` to keep track? A way of saying, the first time I call this function, do this but the second time, do this, then the third time, do this, then go back to the beginning and do what you did first. A function that keeps track of how many times it has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with an iterator, you can do like this:

```
def my_function(a):
    a = iter(a)
    while True:
        yield 10 * next(a)    
        yield next(a)
        yield "foo" + next(a)

a = [2, "foo1", "bar1", 5, "foo3", "bar2", 3, "foo2", "bar3"]    
print list(my_function(a))
#prints [20, 'foo1', 'foobar1', 50, 'foo3', 'foobar2', 30, 'foo2', 'foobar3']
```

If anyone is wondering what happens at the end of the list, `next(a)` will raise `StopIteration`. The exception terminates the generator `my_function`, but code that iterates over it -- in this case `list()` -- will recognize it as a normal end of iteration.

Comment: yep, was about to suggest this. I'd move `iter` to inside `my_function` though.

Comment: I should have thought of this ... *facepalm*.  Although I think I would move the `iter` inside the function.  No reason to keep it out as far as I can see...  +1 anyway.

Comment: @thg435 mgilson: OK, inside the function it is.

Comment: Now that the iterator is inside the function I can see what this is doing, and this is the sort of solution I was thinking of when I asked the question, so accepted! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might do something like:

```
def my_function(lst):
    items = (lst[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 3))
    for group in items:
       yield group[0] * 10
       yield group[1]
       yield 'foo' + group[2]
```

Running on your input:

```
>>> list(my_function(a))
[20, 'foo1', 'foobar1', 50, 'foo3', 'foobar2', 30, 'foo2', 'foobar3']
```

I've made 2 big assumptions here -- that your list is indeed a list (or at least a sequence), and that the length of the sequence is divisible by 3 (otherwise you'll end up with an `IndexError`).  Both of these assumptions could be taken care of without *too* much effort, but I'll leave that as an exercise if you're really interested ;-)

Comment: I like this, yeild seems like the right way to go, though I don't fully understand it yet. Could you explain the second line of your function a little bit for me? That seems to be where the magic happens.

Comment: First look at `xrange` -- It will yield every 3rd number starting at 0 up to (but not including) the length of the list.  so..., `0, 3, 6, 9, ...`.  From there it's just a simple slice to pull off 3 elements.  `lst[0:3], lst[3:6], lst[6:9], ...`.  Those lists of 3 elements are the `group` that gets pulled out of the `items` generator.

Comment: Ah yes, that's very good. Not sure which of the answers is the best though, they're all good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
def my_function (a):
    actions = [lambda l: l * 10,
               lambda l: l,
               lambda l: "foo" + l]
    for i, line in enumerate(a):
        line = actions[i % 3](line)
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option to the existing ones using compination of `zip` and `iter` (explenation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)):

```
def my_function2(a):
    for v1,v2,v3 in zip(*[iter(a)]*3):
        print(v1*10,v2, 'foo'+ v3)

% gives
20 foo1 foobar1
50 foo3 foobar2
30 foo2 foobar3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for this, I find it most elegant and resilient to the number of elements/actions:

```py
import itertools


def my_function(a):
    actions = itertools.cycle(
        (lambda l: l * 10, lambda l: l, lambda l: "foo" + l)
    )

    for val, action in itertools.izip(a, actions):
        yield action(val)

a = [2, "foo1", "bar1", 5, "foo3", "bar2", 3, "foo2", "bar3", 7]
print list(my_function(a))
```

Result:

```
[20, 'foo1', 'foobar1', 50, 'foo3', 'foobar2', 30, 'foo2', 'foobar3', 70]
```

As you can see from the example, this will work even if the elements count is not a multiplication of the actions count (or even less than actions count).

This is python2 version, if you need 3 please specify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` list as an input to the function,

```
def my_function(a):
   a[::3] = map(lambda x: 10*x, a[::3])
   a[2::3] = map(lambda x: "foo"+x, a[2::3])
```

Here I am making use of [extended slices](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) in python. This is more of a pythonic way i think.

Answer (score 0):

This is `C` like way rather than `Pythonic`. So if you know `C` you can understand it just a few seconds.

```
def my_function(a):
    for n, line in enumerate(a):
        if n % 3 == 0:
            line = line * 10
        elif n % 3 == 2:
            line = "foo" + line
        print line
```