# regex to split %ages and values in python

Tags: python, regex

Hello I am new to python and regex.
I have a large CSV file which has a field like, `%age composition` that contains values such as:

`'34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred'`

How would you split this string so that you get a dictionary object:

`{'passed': 34, 'failed': 23, 'deferred': 46}` for each row?

I tried this:

```
for line in csv_lines:
    for match in re.findall('[\d\s%%]*\s', line)
```

but this only took the %age value

Comment: You can take a look at this site to help with regex construction:  http://txt2re.com/.  Otherwise, please show us your attempts so we can help you improve them, rather than just asking someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And if you still want to go with regular expressions, you can use this one:

```
(\w+)%\s(\w+)
```

Which would match one or more alphanumeric characters (alternative: `[0-9a-zA-Z_]+`) followed by `%` sign, space character and one or more alphanumeric characters. Parenthesis help with [capturing](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) appropriate set of characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)%\s(\w+)')
>>> {value: key for key, value in pattern.findall(s)}
{'failed': '23', 'passed': '34', 'deferred': '46'}
```

Comment: You got it in before I did :) and cleaner too

Comment: @Ashwin same here, falsetru made me provide a regex-based approach :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use regular expression:

```
>>> s = '34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred'
>>> groups = zip(*[iter(s.split())]*2)
>>> groups
[('34%', 'passed'), ('23%', 'failed'), ('46%', 'deferred')]
>>> {result: int(percent.rstrip('%')) for percent, result in groups}
{'failed': 23, 'passed': 34, 'deferred': 46}
```

---

`zip(*[iter(..)]*2)` came from [`grouper` - `itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) (Also see [How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)):

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: Might be worth linking to an [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python) of the `zip-iter` magic.

Comment: @DSM, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[EDIT: Added list support for words to check based on OPs request. Also cleaned the dictionary building code that [alecx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) uses here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628562/3646530]

```
import re

data = """34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred 34% checked"""
checkList = ['passed', 'failed', 'deferred', 'checked']
result = {k:v for (v, k) in re.findall('(\d{1,3})% (' + '|'.join(checkList) + ')', data)}
print(result) # Python 3
#print result # Python 2.7
```

Here the regex is \d{1,3} - to catch the percentage int and passed|failed|deferred to get the type. I use a list comprehension to generate a list of tuples of keys and values, which I then convert to a dictionary

In order to build the string 'passed|failed| ..' I use the .join function of a string to join words from a checkList with a pipe character as the separator.

Comment: `\w+` might be better, in case those are just a sample of possible options. Grabbing the immediate word after would be better than a possible list of them.

Comment: so, something like `result = dict([(k,v) for (v, k) in re.findall('(\d{1,3})%\w+', data)])` to grab words after after %age?

Comment: also how would you make `passed|failed|deferred` be linked to a list with other values to check?

Comment: @aqoon edited my answer to support that. Also \w+ will match all the words after that. But in order to grab it, you have to group it. so using (\w+) will group it and make it accessible. Put the regex in a tool like this: https://www.debuggex.com/ to visualize your groups and test your regex