# Capturing named groups in regex with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

When I was trying to answer this question: [regex to split %ages and values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628412/regex-to-split-ages-and-values-in-python) I noticed that I had to re-order the groups from the result of findall. For example:

```
data = """34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred"""
result = {key:value for value, key in re.findall('(\w+)%\s(\w+)', data)}
print(result)
>>> {'failed': '23', 'passed': '34', 'deferred': '46'}
```

Here the result of the findall is:

```
>>> re.findall('(\w+)%\s(\w+)', data)
>>> [('34', 'passed'), ('23', 'failed'), ('46', 'deferred')]
```

Is there a way to change/specify the order of the groups that makes **re.findall return**:

```
[('passed', '34'), ('failed', '23'), ('deferred', '46')]
```

Just to clarify, the question is:

Is it possible to specfic the order or re-order the groups for the return of the re.findall function?

I used the example above to create a dictionary to provide a reason/use case for when you would want to change the order (making key as value and value as key)

Further clarification:

In order to handle groups in larger more complicated regexes, you can name groups, but those names are only accessible when you do a re.search pr re.match. From what I have read, findall has a fixed indices for groups returned in the tuple, The question is anyone know how those indices could be modified. This would help make handling of groups easier and intuitive.

Comment: It is **not** possible to alter the order of the groups returned by `findall`, but it is easy to re-order them after the fact as I showed in my second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25629693/20789

Comment: Thats what I assumed, but could not find documentation to state that. Hence my question here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take 3, based on a further clarification of the OP's intent in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628973/re-ordering-groups-in-regex-findalls/25629693?noredirect=1#comment40043356_25629693).

Ashwin is correct that `findall` does not preserve named capture groups (e.g. `(?P<name>regex)`). [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) to the rescue! It returns the individual match objects one-by-one. Simple example:

```
data = """34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred"""
for m in re.finditer('(?P<percentage>\w+)%\s(?P<word>\w+)', data):
    print( m.group('percentage'), m.group('word') )
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've identified in your second example, `re.findall` returns the groups in the original order.

The problem is that the standard Python **`dict` type does not preserve the order of keys** in any way. Here's the manual for Python 2.x, which makes it explicit, but it's still true in Python 3.x: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

What you should use instead is [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict as odict

data = """34% passed 23% failed 46% deferred"""
result = odict((key,value) for value, key in re.findall('(\w+)%\s(\w+)', data))
print(result)
>>> OrderedDict([('passed', '34'), ('failed', '23'), ('deferred', '46')])
```

Notice that you **must use the pairwise constructor** form (`dict((k,v) for k,v in ...`) rather than the `dict` comprehension constructor (`{k:v for k,v in ...}`). That's because the latter constructs instances of `dict`type, which cannot be converted to `OrderedDict` without losing the order of the keys... which is of course what you are trying to preserve in the first place.

Comment: I was wondering if I can specify or change the original order of the return for re.findall. The conversion to dict was just more of an example of when I want to re-order the groups.

Comment: Your question does not make it clear at all what you are trying to reorder. Please edit it to clarify this.

Comment: **Update:** Python `dict` **does** preserve key ordering for newer versions of Python (**see also** [SPEC](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/42223) )

Answer (score 1):

Per [the OP's comment on my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628973/re-ordering-groups-in-regex-findalls/25629602?noredirect=1#comment40042973_25629602): If you are simply trying to reorder a list of 2-tuples like this:

```
[('34', 'passed'), ('23', 'failed'), ('46', 'deferred')]
```

... to look like this, with individual elements reversed:

```
[('passed', '34'), ('failed', '23'), ('deferred', '46')]
```

There's an easy solution: use a list comprehension with the slicing syntax `sequence[::-1]` to reverse the order of the elements of the individual tuples:

```
a = [('34', 'passed'), ('23', 'failed'), ('46', 'deferred')]
b = [x[::-1] for x in a]
print b
```

Comment: I know how to re-order tuples, the questions is to specific the order to re.findall.

Comment: The order of **what** to `re-findall`? I'm showing you how to take the output of `re.findall` and alter it to have the order you said you wanted.

Comment: In order to handle groups in larger more complicated regexes,  you can name groups, but those names are only accessible when you do a re.search pr re.match. From what I have read, findall has a fixed indices for groups returned in the tuple, The question is anyone know how those indices could be modified. This would help make handling of groups easier and intuitive.

Comment: The documentaion here: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.findall says you will get the list of tuples with groups, but does not talk about the indices of groups in that tuple.

Comment: Ah, named groups are a separate issue (also not in your question). You are correct that `findall` returns only captured groups and ignores names; however you can simply use [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead to return the match objects, by which you will be able to access named groups.

Comment: That sir, was what I was looking for. If you can add/modify your answer, I will accept it. Thanks