# How to add values in keys in a dictionary inside a loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
x=['a','3','4','b','1','2','c','4','5']
```

How can i make the following dictionary:

```
b = {'a':[3,4],'b':[1,2],'c':[4,5]}
```

I tried the following:

```
Category = defaultdict(int)
for i in a:
    if Varius.is_number(i)==False:
        Category[i]=[]
        keys.append(i)
    else:
        Category[keys(i)] = i
```

The keys are created but after i have problem to insert the values.(`is_number` is a function which check if the value of the list is number or string).First day away of MATLAB.First day in Python..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an example that actually uses the feature that `defaultdict` provides over the normal `dict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x=['a','3','4','b','1','2','c','4','5']

key='<unknown>' # needed if the first value of x is a number
category = defaultdict(list)  # defaultdict with list
for i in x:
    if i.isalpha():
        key = i;
    else:
        category[key].append(i) # no need to initialize with an empty list

print category
```

Also: you should use lower case names for class instances. Uppercase names are usually reserved for classes. Read [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) for a style guide.

Answer (score 4):

If the key/value entries in your list `x` are evenly spaced, here's an alternative way to build the dictionary. It uses a few of Python's built in features and functions:

```
>>> keys = x[::3]
>>> values = [map(int, pair) for pair in zip(x[1::3], x[2::3])]
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'a': [3, 4], 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [4, 5]}
```

To explain what's being used here:

- list slicing to create new lists from `x`: `x[start:stop:step]`
- here `zip` takes two lists and makes a list of tuples containing the n-th elements of each list
- `map(int, pair)` turns a tuple of digit strings into a list of integers
- `values` is constructed with list comprehension - the `map` function is applied to each pair
- `dict` turns a list of pairs into dictionary keys/values

Comment: This only addresses the OP's case where the relevantly entries are evenly spaced. I'll make that clear in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(x,lambda x : x.isalpha())]
>>> p=[l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
>>> {i[0]:map(int,j) for i,j in p}
{'a': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted 1 or 3 to be keys.

Comment: @Kevin yes , i miss somthing i'll update ,thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a key on the first positions of your list (`x`) and that after a letter, there will be a number:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x=['a','3','4','b','1','2','c','4','5']

key = x[0]
Category = defaultdict(int)
for i in x:
    if i.isalpha():
        key = i;
    else:
        Category[key].append(i)

print Category
```

Comment: If you initialize each dictionary value with an empty list, there is no need to use `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and some iterator stuff:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby  
>>> it = (next(g) if k else map(int, g) for k, g in groupby(x, str.isalpha))
>>> {k: next(it) for k in it}
{'a': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Here the first iterator will yield something like:

```
>>> [next(g) if k else map(int, g) for k, g in groupby(x, str.isalpha)]
['a', [3, 4], 'b', [1, 2], 'c', [4, 5]]
```

Now as this iterator is going to yield key-value alternately, we can loop over this iterator and get the next item from it(i.e the value) using `next()`

```
>>> it = (next(g) if k else map(int, g) for k, g in groupby(x, str.isalpha))
>>> for k in it:                                                            
    print k,'-->' ,next(it)
...     
a --> [3, 4]
b --> [1, 2]
c --> [4, 5]
```

---

There's another way to consume this iterator that is using `zip`, but it's a [little hard to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233204/846892) IMO:

```
>>> it = (next(g) if k else map(int, g) for k, g in groupby(x, str.isalpha))
>>> dict(zip(*[it]*2))
{'a': [3, 4], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using just `dict` and `list`:

```
>>> category = {}
>>> for i in x:
...     if i.isalpha():
...         items = category[i] = []
...     elif category:
...         items.append(i)
... 
>>> print(category)
{'c': ['4', '5'], 'a': ['3', '4'], 'b': ['1', '2']}
```