# list to dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

This is my list

```
myList = ['Bob', '5-10', 170, 'Tom', '5-5', 145, 'Bill', '6-5', '215']
```

I want to make into a dictionary like this.

```
{'Bob': ['5-10', 170], 'Bill': ['6-5', '215'], 'Tom': ['5-5', 145]}
```

I came up with this but it is very ugly and doesn't scale up.

```
def MakeDict():
    d = {}
    for x, i  in zip(myList, range(len(myList))):
       if i in (0, 3, 6):
           name = x
       elif i in (1, 4, 7):
           hieght = x
       elif i in (2, 5, 8):
           wieght = x
          d[name] = [hieght, wieght]
return d
```

What can I do?

Comment: For starters, you could indent your sample code, it would make it more readable.

Comment: FYI, you can replace the `zip(...)` call with `enumerate(myList)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Convert your list to an iterator
- Now loop over it to get the keys.
- For values during each iteration call [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on the iterator. Then call `list()` on the slice object to get a list.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> myList = ['Bob', '5-10', 170, 'Tom', '5-5', 145, 'Bill', '6-5', '215']
>>> it = iter(myList)
>>> {key: list(islice(it, 2)) for key in it}
{'Bob': ['5-10', 170], 'Bill': ['6-5', '215'], 'Tom': ['5-5', 145]}
```

---

If you don't want to import anything use [`zip(*[iterator]*n)` magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python):

```
>>> {key: [height, weight]  for key, height, weight in zip(*[iter(myList)]*3)}
{'Bob': ['5-10', 170], 'Bill': ['6-5', '215'], 'Tom': ['5-5', 145]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use itertools.

Here is pushing you in the right direction:

```
from itertools import islice
```

See the examples at [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: It actually answers the question (or at least makes a good attempt at it).