# Numpy where returning non expected values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the index of elements in a row that is filled.

I tried to use numpy [where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function, but it's only returning the index of non-zero elements.

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 2, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
for rows in board:
    if set(rows) == {2}:
        if len(set(rows)) <= 1:
            print(np.where(board == rows))
```

My desired output is the following:

```
(array([9, 9, 9, 9], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

that is, row, col.

However, I'm getting this instead:

```
(array([2, 9, 9, 9, 9], dtype=int32), array([1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

As stated above, it should only get the index of elements in a filled row. The board[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is not filled with 2's, yet it's being included.

Comment: What's the expected o/p?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Would you please provide a sample of your desired output given the `board` array you listed in your question?

Comment: You actually don't need the second `if`, because `set(rows) == {2}` will only return `True` if the sets are equal, and the second row is `{0, 2}` which is not equal to `{2}`. Anyways, the reason it's returning more than the row you want is because `board==rows` still returns `False, True, False, False` at row 2, and so that `True` value is still included in the argument for `np.where()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loops for this at all. For finding the rows that are filled with something other than 0, use [`.all(axis=1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). The `axis` argument tells which axis to look for matching values across:

```
>>> (board != 0).all(axis=1)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
    True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The booleans are `True` wherever there is a row filled with non-zero values, and `False` otherwise. If you take the [`outer` product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) with a row array full of `True` values, you'll get `True` exactly in your matrix locations corresponding to the full row:

```
>>> np.outer((board!=0).all(axis=1),np.ones(board.shape[1], dtype=bool))
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then you can get the indices of those `True` values with [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(np.outer((board!=0).all(axis=1),np.ones(board.shape[1], dtype=bool)))
(array([9, 9, 9, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Note that `np.where()` returns `np.int64` values. If you want `np.int32` then just assign variables and convert them:

```
>>> yind, xind = np.where(np.outer((board!=0).all(axis=1),np.ones(board.shape[1], dtype=bool)))
>>> yind = np.int32(yind)
>>> xind = np.int32(xind)
>>> yind, xind
(array([9, 9, 9, 9], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

To instead put all of these indices as tuples, use `zip(*)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python) for an explanation if you're not familiar with `*` unpacking):

```
>>> [(y,x) for y,x in zip(*np.where(np.outer((board!=0).all(1), np.ones(board.shape[1]))))]
[(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3)]
```

And again if you need `np.int32` just specify that in the comprehension:

```
>>> [(y.astype(np.int32),x.astype(np.int32)) for y,x in zip(*np.where(np.outer((board == 2).all(1), np.ones(board.shape[1]))))]
[(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to come up with this: `y, x = np.where(np.outer((board == 2).all(1), np.ones(board.shape[1])))

pending_rows_indices = [(y, x) for x, y in zip(x, y)]

print(pending_rows_indices)` I have one more question, is there a way to write this with list comprehension? Using zip as well.

Comment: @CastFellow sure, use `zip(*np.where(...))`. E.g. `pending_row_indices = [(y,x) for y,x in zip(*np.where(np.outer((board == 2).all(1), np.ones(board.shape[1]))))]` gives you `[(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3)]`. I edited my post to include this at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well you are trying to find the row where your numpy array is completely filled ( no 0 values )

so i ask of you to consider this:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 2, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1],   # added this one just to generalize in 
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],   # case you have numbers != 2
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
for i,rows in enumerate(board):
    if not 0 in set(rows): # changed this to work on all non zero numbers
        print(rows)
        if len(set(rows)) <= 1:
            print(i)
```

output:

```
[1 1 1 1] # first row filled
3         # its index as int ( if that's what you're looking for )
[2 2 2 2] # seconds row filled
9         # its index as int
```

all you needed is [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to find the row index of a specific element in the array. So, you need the following `print()` statement instead of `print(np.where(board == rows))`.

```
print(np.where((board == rows).all(axis=1)))
```

It outputs:

```
(array([9], dtype=int64),)
```

To get the specific row number, you can do the following.

```
loc = np.where((board == rows).all(axis=1))
print(loc[0][0]) # prints 9
```

Complete program:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 2, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0]])
for rows in board:
    if set(rows) == {2}:
        print(rows)
        if len(set(rows)) <= 1:
            print(np.where((board == rows).all(axis=1)))
```