# How to club certain parts of list: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-concatenation

I have a sample list of strings:

```
my_list = ['hello','this','is','a','sample','list', 'thanks', 'for', 'help']
```

And I want to club every three elements together, like:

```
new_list = ['hello this is', 'a sample list', 'thanks for help']
```

Answer (score 4):

Just split into chunks and join:

```
[' '.join(my_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: This solution drop elements if `my_list` length is not divisible by 3

input string: `['hello','this','is','a','sample','list', 'thanks', 'for', 'help', 'foo']`

```
[" ".join(i) for i in zip(*[iter(my_list)]*3)]
```

result: `['hello this is', 'a sample list', 'thanks for help']`

how python iter trick works: [How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

### Option 2: keep extra element with `zip_longest`

input string: `['hello','this','is','a','sample','list', 'thanks', 'for', 'help', 'foo']`

```
[" ".join(i) for i in zip_longest(*[iter(my_list)]*3, fillvalue='')]
```

result: `['hello this is', 'a sample list', 'thanks for help', 'foo  ']`

Comment: Note, this approach will leave off anything at the end if the length of the list isn't divisible by 3. This may or may not be a problem, but it is probably worth noting

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by iterating using a step, in this case 3 steps, and adding the individual strings under each step, i.e., `my_list[i]`, `my_list[i+1]`. `my_list[i+2 ]`. Note that you need to add a space after each first and second string. This piece of code does that:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3):
    if i + 2 < len(my_list):
        new_list.append(my_list[i] + ' ' + my_list[i+1] + ' ' + my_list[i+2])
print(new_list)
```

The output is as expected:

```
['hello this is', 'a sample list', 'thanks for help']
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) are possible.

Using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
[' '.join(x[1] for x in g) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(my_list), lambda x: x[0] // 3)]
```

Using [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
a, b = tee(my_list)
next(b)
b, c = tee(b)
next(c)
[' '.join(items) for items in zip_longest(a, b, c, fillvalue='')]
```

Using just `zip_longest`:

```
[' '.join(g) for g in zip_longest(*[iter(my_list)] * 3, fillvalue='')]
```

The last two are adapted from the `pairwise` and `grouper` [recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the documentation. Only the first option won't add extra spaces at the end of your last group if the aren't a multiple of 3 words.