# Dataframe apply balanced allocation of rows to lists based on row type

Tags: python, random, data-science, python-itertools, data-munging

I have a dataframe with 192 rows , each rows represent a sentence with some metadata and a specific type (H or L). So, for each type I have total of 96 sentences.
I need to allocate them to 10 different lists with the following conditions:

1. Each list has 6 sub-lists with the size of 16 each
2. Each sub-list has equal number of sentences from each type (8 H and 8 L)
3. Each list has exactly one sentence from each of the 96 sets (So one sentence from each set and total of 96 sentences per list, 48 H and 48 L)
4. Across the 10 lists, for each set , there will be 5 sentences from the type H and 5 sentences type L. Meaning, there will be a balance of the number of allocation of type per specific condition.

   So, if we take set#1 as an example - the sentence "  I went to work" will appear in 5 lists (anywhere in the list - meaning the sublist doesn't matter at all in this point)  , and the sentence "She went to work" will appear in the **other** 5 lists.
5. The allocation of specific sentence per list and sub-list shoud be as randomly as possible

And example of a dataframe is:

```
SetNum       Sentence         Type   Index
1          I went to work      H       0
1          She went to work    L       1
2          I drink coffee      H       2
2          She drinks coffee   L       3
3          The desk is red     H       4
3          The desk is white   L       5
4          The TV is big       H       6
4          The TV is white     L       7
5          This is a car       H       8
5          This is a plane     L       9

..
96         Good morning        H       194
96         Good night          L       195
```

How can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of one such list? Also could you elaborate on point 4?

Comment: @SayandipDutta It's impossible to create example without using all the data as the numbers should be matched and divided perfectly - I added on #4 , is it clear now?

Comment: It is hard to code something without the data in hand, I will try to give a general idea, there may be some bugs, which I guess you will be able to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np
# groups by type 'H' and 'L', makes list, and assigns to corresponding variables
H_, L_ = df.groupby('Type')['Sentence'].agg(list)

# initialize empty dict (actually list, I did it for better visualization)
dict_of_list = {}

# loop 10 times for creating each list
for j in range(10):
    random_idx = random.sample(range(96), 48)
    H_idx = np.isin(range(96), random_idx)
    L_idx = ~H_idx
    H, L = np.array(H_)[H_idx].tolist(), np.array(L_)[L_idx].tolist()
    H, L = random.sample(H, len(H)), random.sample(L,len(L))

    # then zip together and chain them, to make a sequence of [H, L, H, L, ...]
    pair_wise_list = list(chain(*zip(H,L)))

    # zip(*[iter(pair_wise_list)]*16) divides the entire list in sublist of 16
    # more about zip(*[iter(pair_wise_list)]*16) in reference below
    # random.sample(list(i),len(i)) adds more randomness in positions of H,L in sublist
    lst = [random.sample(list(i),len(i)) for i in zip(*[iter(pair_wise_list)]*16)]

    dict_of_list[j] = lst
```

I copied 10 rows. Made 10 list, each containing 5 sublists, which contain 2 sentences from each type. Across the 10 list, each sentence is repeated only once, and balanced.

```
>>> df
   SetNum           Sentence Type  Index
0       1     I went to work    H      0
1       1   She went to work    L      1
2       2     I drink coffee    H      2
3       2  She drinks coffee    L      3
4       3    The desk is red    H      4
5       3  The desk is white    L      5
6       4      The TV is big    H      6
7       4    The TV is white    L      7
8       5      This is a car    H      8
9       5    This is a plane    L      9

>>> import random
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> H, L = df.groupby('Type')['Sentence'].agg(list)

>>> dict_of_list = {}
>>> for j in range(10):
...     H, L = random.sample(H, len(H)), random.sample(L, len(L))
...     pair_wise_list = list(chain(*zip(H,L)))
...     lst = [random.sample(list(i),len(i)) for i in zip(*[iter(pair_wise_list)]*2)] # had to change to 2
...     dict_of_list[j] = lst
>>> dict_of_list

{0: [['The desk is white', 'I drink coffee'],
  ['This is a car', 'The TV is white'],
  ['She went to work', 'The TV is big'],
  ['I went to work', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['This is a plane', 'The desk is red']],
 1: [['She went to work', 'The TV is big'],
  ['I went to work', 'The desk is white'],
  ['This is a car', 'This is a plane'],
  ['The TV is white', 'The desk is red'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'She drinks coffee']],
 2: [['The desk is red', 'The TV is white'],
  ['The TV is big', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['I went to work', 'This is a plane'],
  ['She went to work', 'This is a car'],
  ['The desk is white', 'I drink coffee']],
 3: [['The desk is red', 'The TV is white'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['She went to work', 'I went to work'],
  ['This is a car', 'This is a plane'],
  ['The desk is white', 'The TV is big']],
 4: [['I went to work', 'This is a plane'],
  ['The desk is red', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['The TV is white', 'This is a car'],
  ['The TV is big', 'The desk is white'],
  ['She went to work', 'I drink coffee']],
 5: [['She drinks coffee', 'This is a car'],
  ['She went to work', 'I went to work'],
  ['The desk is white', 'The TV is big'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'The TV is white'],
  ['The desk is red', 'This is a plane']],
 6: [['This is a plane', 'The TV is big'],
  ['She drinks coffee', 'I went to work'],
  ['She went to work', 'This is a car'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'The TV is white'],
  ['The desk is white', 'The desk is red']],
 7: [['The desk is red', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['This is a car', 'The TV is white'],
  ['The TV is big', 'She went to work'],
  ['I went to work', 'The desk is white'],
  ['This is a plane', 'I drink coffee']],
 8: [['I went to work', 'She went to work'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'The desk is white'],
  ['The TV is big', 'The TV is white'],
  ['The desk is red', 'She drinks coffee'],
  ['This is a plane', 'This is a car']],
 9: [['She went to work', 'The TV is big'],
  ['I went to work', 'The TV is white'],
  ['I drink coffee', 'The desk is white'],
  ['This is a plane', 'This is a car'],
  ['She drinks coffee', 'The desk is red']]}
```

**EDIT**:
To get all the contents, change the first few lines to this:

```
import random
from itertools import chain
# groups by type 'H' and 'L', makes list, and assigns to corresponding variables
df2 = df.copy()
df2['joined'] = df.astype(str).agg(', '.join,1)
H, L = df2.groupby('Type')['joined'].agg(list)
```

Reference:

[How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, How can I set the size of the sub-lists? (  I need to have 6 sub-lists of 16 sentences for each of the 10 lists)

Comment: This line creates such: `lst = [random.sample(list(i),len(i)) for i in zip(*[iter(pair_wise_list)]*16)]`

Comment: Here `lst == [[], [], [], [], ..., upto 32]`

Comment: You may have to take `dict_of_list[j] = lst[:16]`

Comment: @okuoub if it worked for you, you may consider upvoting/accepting.

Comment: Its seems to be working fine thanks! However I won't be able to completely validate including edge cases before Thursday

Comment: Is it possible to get the entire row instead of just the sentence?

Comment: Would comma-separated elements for each row do?

Comment: Yes, also I detected a problem - it creates 12 lists of 16 instead of 6 lists - only 96 elements should appears in each list (one per set) - please see point #3

Comment: Yes, that is why I said: "You may have to take dict_of_list[j] = lst[:16]". I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but if I take dict_of_list[j] = lst[:16] if it ensure each list will have exactly one sentence per set? I can't understand why it happens

Comment: To ensure that you have to do: `H, L = H[:48], L[:48]` after creating `H,L`. So you essentially discard 96 elements. That is because you have 192 elems, and you want 96 sets, with each set having a single sentence.

Comment: But Then how can I ensure that the appearances of H,L for each set will be balanced across lists? 
Meaning, that for example for set#1 - the sentence 'I went to work' will appear in 5 lists and 'She went to work' will appear in the other 5?

Comment: Try using this: `H, L = H[:48], L[:48]` before you enter the loop, you will see that it works. There will be same number of H and Ls in each sublist, in each list. And for each set, exactly one sentence would be there. If you for some reason want to reduce the randomness, you can replace `random.sample(list(i),len(i))` with simply `list(i)`.

Comment: OK Thank I will validate all the balancing soon. Anyway , I get the error: TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found', 'occurred at index 0')
For the line df2['joined'] = df.agg(' '.join,1)

Comment: Ahh, sorry it will be `df.astype(str).agg(', '.join,1)` I will update

Comment: Hi , I checked it but I see that I sometimes get the same set_num twice for the same list. There are 6 sublist in every list, and there should be only sentence per set in the same list. I suspect that this happens because the line H, L = H[:48], L[:48] as the max set_num is 47 in every list - I can't understand why this line is needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208557/discussion-between-sayandip-dutta-and-okuoub).

Comment: please notice this is not yet working because rule#4 is violated

Comment: I will check in an hour