# How to split a string with specific character with python in a nested list?

Tags: python, string, split, nested-lists

I have a nested list with some strings. I want to split strings with '-' character in an odd interval, as myresult showed. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character). But it couldn't help me.

```
mylist= [['1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6'],['1 - 2 - 3 - 4']]

myresult = [[['1 - 2'] , ['3 - 4'] , ['5 - 6']],[['1 - 2] ,[ 3 - 4']]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
res = []
for x in mylist:
    data = list(map(str.strip, x[0].split('-')))
    res.append([[' - '.join(data[y * 2: (y + 1) * 2])] for y in range(0, len(data) // 2)])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[['1 - 2'], ['3 - 4'], ['5 - 6']], [['1 - 2'], ['3 - 4']]]
```

Comment: There are some useless spaces, you should remove them as the OP doesn't want them

Answer (score 1):

In case you prefer a one line solution, here it is!

```
res = [[[s] for s in map(' - '.join,
                         map(lambda x: map(str, x),
                             zip(x[::2], x[1::2])))]
       for lst in mylist for x in (lst[0].split(' - '),)]
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension:

```
[[[" - ".join(item)] for item in zip(*[iter(sub.split(" - "))]*2)] for l in mylist for sub in l]
```

Did some changes from [How does zip(*[iter(s)]*n) work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)