# I have a list of tuples that have different length so I need to iterate over list

Tags: python, loops, tuples

The tuple that length is equal to 6 is correct one while the tuples with shorter length are artefacts that should be joined to give length of 6.

For example:

I have a list of tuples as below:

```
foo = [(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1),  (3, 1, 0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]

len(foo[0]) = 6
len(foo[1]) = 2
len(foo[2]) = 2
len(foo[3]) = 2
len(foo[4]) = 4
len(foo[5]) = 2
len(foo[6]) = 6
```

So it means that I want to have a list with the following output:

```
foo_1 = [(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]
```

where:

```
foo_1[1] = foo[1] + foo[2] + foo[3], 
foo_1[2] = foo[4] + foo[5]
```

Basically, I need to iterate over list of tuples and compare the length of each with 6. Then if the length of tuple is not equal to six I have to join tuples till their length will be 6.

Comment: What if the total number of values isn't a multiple of 6?

Comment: I tried something like that below but I can't get the output I want.                                                                         ls = []
for i in range(len(foo)):
    if len(foo[i]) == 6:
        ls.append(foo[i])
    else:
        ls.append(foo[i] + foo[i+1])

Comment: Your own example *explicitly* shows that sometimes you need 3 tuples to combine into one of length 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function that flatten's the list of tuples, and then use generators and zip to group them into proper number of length.

```
>>> def flatten(lst):
        for tup in lst:
            yield from tup

>>> list(zip(*[flatten(foo)]*6))
[(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2),
 (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]
```

You can find more about how `zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233204/5431791).

Or you can use the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` function to accomplish the `flattening` part:

```
>>> flat = chain.from_iterable(foo)

>>> list(zip(*[flat]*6))
[(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2),
 (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
foo=[(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1),  (3, 1, 0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]
foo1=[i for t in foo for i in t]
list(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(foo1)]*6))
```

Output:

```
[(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2),
 (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]
```

Or just iterate over and use slice

```
[foo1[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(foo1),6)]
```

`foo1` is list of all elements..and after that we can use `slicing` or `zip_longest` from itertools to get the desired result.

[itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
> If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
> with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
> exhausted. Roughly equivalent to:

If the total length is not in  multiples of 6

```
foo=[(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1),  (3, 1, 0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2),(1,)
```

I've added an extra `(1,)`

```
list(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(foo1)]*6))
(1, None, None, None, None, None)]
```

If we need some fill value instead of `None` then

```
list(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(foo1)]*6,fillvalue=2))
(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get the results could use [more_itertools.chunked](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=chunked#more_itertools.chunked)

```
from more_itertools import chunked
from itertools import chain

foo = [(3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (3, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1),
       (3, 1, 0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2)]

for chunk in chunked(chain.from_iterable(foo), 6):
    print(chunk)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2]
```