# How to split a text that repeat all the same pattern of lines n times and create n different text files in python?

Tags: python

I have a text that repeat the same pattern of lines.
like that:

---

```
 "User= Name1; 
  Time= HH:MM; 
  Note= example.
  User= Name2; 
  Time= HH:MM; 
  Note= example2.
  ......"
```

this pattern is repeated 500 times.

how can i create 500 different text files, each for each "user"?

Comment: all the data has to be same in all those 500 text files ? or you have a plan to supply data from other data structure  ?

Comment: No. "user", "time" and "note" change every time. It's just the pattern the same all the times. Every file text should have the same pattern with different data

Comment: TEXT1:
User=Name1;
Time= time1;
Note= note1;
-------
TEXT2:
User=Name2;
Time= time2;
Note= note2;

and so on

Answer (score 1):

It looks like each segment is 7 lines long, so you can read the data into a list, the use zip and iter to break it into a list of lists, each list being 7 elements long.  Then you can write each one of those to a file.

If you are curious how zip(iter) works check out the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233204/how-does-zipitersn-work-in-python)

```
with open('users.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
       
for c, file in  enumerate(zip(*[iter(data)]*7)):
    with open(f'file_{c}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(file)
```

Or if you want the files names by the users

```
with open('users.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
       
for file in zip(*[iter(data)]*7):
    name = file[0].split('=')[-1].split(';')[0].strip()
    print(name)
    with open(f'file_{name}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(file)
```

Comment: It was so easy! 
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Also, instead of answering questions that demonstrate no effort on OP's part, I'd suggest a better strategy to deal with such questions
is to add a comment pointing them in the right direction, and flag to close. Giving OP the code they are asking for doesn't help
them because they won't learn, and it doesn't help the community because it encourages more basic questions without showing their research/coding effort.