# Query regarding pagination in tweepy (get_followers) of a particular twitter user

Tags: python, twitter, pagination, tweepy

I am fairly new to tweepy and pagination using the cursor class. I have been trying to user the cursor class to get all the followers of a particular twitter user but I keep getting the error where it says `"tweepy.error.TweepError: This method does not perform pagination"`
Hence I would really appreciate any help if someone could please help me achieve this task of obtaining all the followers of a particular twitter user with pagination, using tweepy. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key='xyz'
consumer_secret='xyz'

access_token='abc'
access_token_secret='def'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


user = api.get_user('somehandle')
print user.name

followers = tweepy.Cursor(user.followers)
temp=[]
for user in followers.items():
    temp.append(user)
    print temp
#the following part works fine but that is without pagination so I will be able to retrieve at #most 100 followers
aDict =  user.followers()
for friend in aDict:
    friendDict = friend.__getstate__()
    print friendDict['screen_name']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a handy method called `followers_ids`. It returns up to 5000 followers ([twitter api limit](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)) ids for the given `screen_name` (or `id`, `user_id` or `cursor`).

Then, you can paginate these results manually in python and call `lookup_users` for every chunk. As long as `lookup_users` can handle only 100 user ids at a time ([twitter api limit](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)), it's pretty logical to set chunk size to 100.

Here's the code (pagination part was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744531/771848)):

```
import itertools
import tweepy


def paginate(iterable, page_size):
    while True:
        i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
        iterable, page = (itertools.islice(i1, page_size, None),
                list(itertools.islice(i2, page_size)))
        if len(page) == 0:
            break
        yield page


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<consumer_key>, <consumer_secret>)
auth.set_access_token(<key>, <secret>)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

followers = api.followers_ids(screen_name='gvanrossum')

for page in paginate(followers, 100):
    results = api.lookup_users(user_ids=page)
    for result in results:
        print result.screen_name
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you by chance have a link to further information on how you created the paginate function? I have been looking for a good way to do that for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleSponable it was long ago, but take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744451/is-this-how-you-paginate-or-is-there-a-better-algorithm) - I think it is where I've taken the `paginate()` function.

Comment: @alecxe Does this allow one to address the limit?