# get tweets with specific status ids using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, status, tweepy

I have a list of the specific status ids of tweets that I need to obtain.
The tweepy documentation provides the following:

```
 API.get_status(id)

Returns a single status specified by the ID parameter.
Parameters: id – The numerical ID of the status.
Return type:    Status object
```

I can't work out how to use this or find any examples.
Is this even the right thing?

My list of ids is 2240 items long and looks something like this:

```
response_ids = [717289507981107201, 717289501337509888, ..., 716684885411237888]
```

These ids were obtained from the 'in_response_to_status_id' field of tweets that I already have (I want to match the tweets I have to the tweets that they were written in response to).

I basically want to write something like

```
for id in response_ids:
    tweet = API.get_status(id)
```

Any help on how to do this, or advice about whether this is possible, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've worked it out.

`get_status` does seem to be the right thing to use, although I initially had some problems with pagination errors. I've hacked some code found in response to another [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265082/query-regarding-pagination-in-tweepy-get-followers-of-a-particular-twitter-use) to come up with this solution:

```
def paginate(iterable, page_size):
    while True:
        i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iterable)
        iterable, page = (itertools.islice(i1, page_size, None),
                list(itertools.islice(i2, page_size)))
        if len(page) == 0:
            break
        yield page

index = 0
for page in paginate(response_ids, 1):
    result = api.get_status(response_ids[index])._json
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use the 'statuses_lookup' command. More infor in the below link http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.statuses_lookup

Before running the below program, get the consumer key and tokens.

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = xxxx
consumer_secret = xxxx
access_token = xxxx
access_token_secret = xxxx

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_list) # id_list is the list of tweet ids
tweet_txt = []
for i in tweets:
    tweet_txt.append(i.text)
```