# Parsing ip address with dpkt

Tags: python, parsing, pcap

I am using dpkt to parse a pcap file, however I am confused about how to extract the destination ip address. I am parsing the packets using `eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)` which returns an ethernet object which looks like the following:

```
Ethernet(src='\x00\x1a\xa0kUf', dst='\x00\x13I\xae\x84,', data=IP(src='\xc0\xa8\n\n',
off=16384, dst='C\x17\x030', sum=25129, len=52, p=6, id=51105, data=TCP(seq=9632694,
off_x2=128, ack=3382015884, win=54, sum=65372, flags=17, dport=80, sport=56145)))
```

I am confused about 2 things.

1. Should I be grabbing the dst field in Ethernet, or the one in IP (Ethernet.data)?
2. How can I turn these weird strings into ip addresses of the form x.x.x.x where x is an integer from 0-255?

I tried a solution like [Convert "little endian" hex string to IP address in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197974/convert-little-endian-hex-string-to-ip-address-in-python), but both dst fields seem to sometimes contain data which seemingly cannot be parsed to an ip address such as `_daQ` (how is _daQ parsed to address?) or `RT\x00\x125\x02` (what is RT?) or `33\x00\x01\x00\x03` (what is the 33 at the beginning and why does this look like 5 bytes not 4?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. The `eth.dst` field will contain the destination MAC address (e.g. `01:23:45:67:89:ab`), not the destination IP address. You need the ip.dst field.
2. The strings are byte strings, rather than ASCII (or otherwise) encoded readable character strings.

Try this:

```
ip_hdr = eth.data
ip_hdr.dst  # will contain your destination IP address in BINARY

# adapted from http://www.commercialventvac.com/dpkt.html#mozTocId303989
import socket
dst_ip_addr_str = socket.inet_ntoa(ip_hdr.dst)
```